# how to return false if input is empty using script in Cutom_functions.php for wordpress thesis theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-thesis-theme

I have a script that I have somehow managed to create (since my knowledge of php is very limited) that basically places author's profile (image, bio, and links to social media) on to authors archive page with all the posts by same author.

the problem with this script is it returns empty href's and src's in the div's if inputs in the authors profile are empty. I understand the reason why it does this, but I do not know how to correct it.

the second problem is if author set up a custom image link that my script returns that image, but what also like to do in case if input for that link is empty is to return an avatar.

Here is my script

```
    /***********************************************************
******************* Custom Author Page *********************
***********************************************************/
function author_info() {
if (is_author($avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt)) {
 if(get_query_var('author_name'))
      $author = get_userdatabylogin(get_query_var('author_name'));
      $authorID = $author->ID;
      $custom_avatar = get_the_author_meta('imageurl', $authorID);
    if ($authorID=="1")
    echo ' ';
    else 
 echo '<div class="author_profile author_'. $authorID .'">
        <div class="author_avatar"><img alt="Author" src="'. $custom_avatar .'" width="140" height="140" /></div>
            <div class="author_info"> 
                <div class="author_description">
                <p>'. get_the_author_meta('description', $authorID) .'</p> 
                <p><strong>Author\'s Website:</strong><a href="'. get_the_author_meta('user_url', $authorID) .'">'. get_the_author_meta('wesitename', $authorID) .'</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="author_links">
            <a href="https://plus.google.com/'. get_the_author_meta('google_plus', $authorID) .'" rel="me" target="_blank"><img alt="Google Plus Profile" src="'. get_the_author_meta('google_plus_icon', $authorID) .'" width="128" height="64" /></a>
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/'. get_the_author_meta('facebook', $authorID) .'" target="_blank"><img alt="Facebook Page" src="'. get_the_author_meta('facebook_icon', $authorID) .'" width="128" height="64" /></a>
            <a href="http://twitter.com/'. get_the_author_meta('twitter', $authorID) .'" target="_blank"><img alt="Twitter Page" src="'. get_the_author_meta('twitter_icon', $authorID) .'" width="128" height="64" /></a>
            <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/'. get_the_author_meta('linkedin', $authorID) .'" target="_blank"><img alt="LinkedIn Profile" src="'. get_the_author_meta('linkedin_icon', $authorID) .'" width="128" height="64" /></a>
            </div>
       </div>
       ';
  ?>
<?php }
}
add_action('thesis_hook_before_content', 'author_info');
```

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Just add this line: `return false;`.

Comment: I though that too, but do not know where, as I said I do not know php well enough

Answer (score 0):

You can change the function: get_the_author_meta($type, $id) to return a default value.

```
get_the_author_meta($type, $id) {
    **Code to get value ** 
    if(isset($value)) {
        return $value;
    } else {
        return "#"; // Or some other string
    }
}
```

However this solution will mean the links will still show up. If you do not want the links to show up at all you could do:

```
if(isset(get_the_author_meta('google_plus', $authorID)) && isset(get_the_author_meta('google_plus_icon', $authorID))) :
<a href="https://plus.google.com/'. get_the_author_meta('google_plus', $authorID) .'" rel="me" target="_blank"><img alt="Google Plus Profile" src="'. get_the_author_meta('google_plus_icon', $authorID) .'" width="128" height="64" /></a>
endif;
```

Then only the links that have a href and a img will show up.

For your avatar you could return a default value. In your code find the place where `get_the_author_meta('imageurl', $authorID);`
goes. Probably a function like getImageUrl().
In that function do something similar as before:

```
getImageUrl() {
    **Code to get url ** 
    if(isset($value)) {
        return $value;
    } else {
        return "http://www.mysite.com/img/base-avatar.png"; // Or some other base image
    }
}
```

Comment: HI Nicky, thanks for trying to help me, but I do not know where to start with all this, sorry! can you please post a code so that I can understand what goes where? thanks!